# Angular2 typescript error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Y'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert http response into DTO object but I am unable to achieve it Please help.
 Here I have service which are using adopter class that 
  converting the response to array of object and returning to controller, 
while assigning the http service response to controller this variable its giving error." error TS2339: Property 'collectionArray' does not exist on type'Collection[]'"

**DTO:**

```
export class Collection {

private collectionId: number;
private image: string;
private url:string;
private title:string;
private description:string;

  static getCollection(responseData) {
    var obj = new Collection();
    obj.setCollection_id(responseData.collection_id);
    obj.setImage_url(responseData.image_url);
    obj.setUrl(responseData.url);
    obj.setTitle(responseData.title);
    obj.setDescription(responseData.description);
    return obj;
  };
//getter setter
}


   **Controller:**

        import { Collection } from '../model/collection';

        import {CollectionService} from './collection.service';

         public collections : Collection[] = [];

        //calling service
        this.collectionService.getCollection().subscribe(
              data => {
                 // giving error here
                 this.collections = data.collectionArray
              },
              err => {
                 console.log(err);
              });

        **service :** 

         getCollection() : Observable<Collection[]>{
                 // ...using get request
                 var options = new RequestOptions({
                    headers: new Headers({
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'user-key' : '7d5ef14e15e096400df74871'
                    })
                  });
               return this.http.get(this.url, options)
              //returning arry of colletion object
                 .map((res:Response) =>  new CollectionAdapter(res.json()))
                   .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

                 }

        **Adapter:**

        export class CollectionAdapter{

            public collectionArray : Collection[] = [];

            constructor(responseData){
              this.getCollectionList(responseData.collections);
            };

            getCollectionList(response) {
                for (var collectionObj of response) {
                  let collObj = collectionObj.collection;
                  let obj = Collection.getCollection(collObj);
                  this.collectionArray.push(obj)
                }
                return this.collectionArray;
            };
          }
```

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` right before the error, what do you see? Probably `this.collections = data` is good enough

Comment: @aletzo I am seeing the correct expected data which is an array of object  but while using "." to access this.collections = data.collectionArray its giving error error TS2339: Property 'collectionArray' does not exist on type'Collection[]'"

Comment: If `data` is an array, then you cannot do `data.collectionArray`. Maybe the answer below can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

**if the error is on compile**

it's probably because your service is returning :

```
 getCollection() : Observable<Collection[]>
```

try changing it to

```
 getCollection() : Observable<CollectionAdapter>
```

**if the error happens on runtime**

use console.log(data) to see what the output is

Comment: Yes I used log to console the data and its right and showing an array of object but while using "." to access this.collections = data.collectionArray its giving error error TS2339: Property 'collectionArray' does not exist on type'Collection[]'"

Comment: I didn't get why do we use
 getCollection() : Observable<CollectionAdapter>
 even we require to return any array of Collection class not a single class

Comment: you are using  .map((res:Response) =>  new CollectionAdapter(res.json())), so what happens it returns Observable<CollectionAdapter> instead of Observable<Collection[]>